# Error While Trying to make git pull/push on Ubuntu server

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-18.04

a new server has been given me, but I been unable to make a git pull/push, the error:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The permissions on the git repository have been given to me, but I just can do git pull/push in local.

Any Idea?

Comment: There is a problem with your SSH access key. Make sure you are using the correct SSH keypair and have added the correct ssh public key to your GitHub account.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Permission+denied+publickey